# Azure function in portal, view files and integrated settings not in sync

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

My azure function has two versions of the function.json showing, 1 from files and 1 from integrated settings. How do I get them to sync and which one wins and why?

The function is a blob trigger function in JS - that shouldn't matter but just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they are already synchronized, however sometimes the changes in the function.json won't show immediately, you could refresh it or wait some time.

If you still have confusion, you could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings), there is a description about the function in Advanced editor:

> The portal provides a UI for this configuration, but you can edit the
>   file directly by opening the Advanced editor available via the
>   Integrate tab of your function.

So this is equivalent to opening function.json in  [`App Service Editor`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX10M.png).